# Save list of records and fields into django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I receive this list from my website admin:

```
[['present', '2'],['present', '1'], ['study', '1'], ['study', '3'], ['present', '4'], ['study', '4'],
```

The first option is actually the field name that needs to be edit in Rollcall model and the second option is the user ID.

Now I want to save this list to the `Rollcall` model:

```
#models.py 
class Rollcall(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User)
    present = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    study = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

So I first check and find the various fields that a particular user has in the list,
 and then I will save all those fields for one user in my model. **How can I do this?**

**--Update 1:** 
this is `HTML` file:

```
{% forstudent in students %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{student}} </td>
                                <td> <input type="radio" name="present_{{student.id}}" value="1"></td>
                                <td> <input type="radio" name="study_{{student.id}}" value="1"></td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
```

I get the data in this way and put them into the list that I explain in the first of this question:

```
data_list = [key.split('_') for key in request.POST.keys()][1:]
```

Each student can be present or absent or can study or not.my exactly question is: **How can save data of all my student?Is there another way to solve this problem without `data_list` or any other way to create better `data_list`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
l=[['present', '2'], ['present', '3'], ['present', '4'], ['study', '2']]
dic={}
for arr in l:
    dic.setdefault(arr[1], []).append(arr[0])
for key in dic:
    Rollcall.objects.create(present=True if 'present' in dic[key] else False,\
    student=True if 'student' in dic[key] else False, \
    study=User.objects.get(id=int(key)))
```

or to make it in bulk after creating the dictionary (`dic`):

```
final_objects = [Rollcall(is_present=True if 'present' in final_dic[key] else False,
                          is_study=True if 'study' in final_dic[key] else False,
                          student=User.objects.get(id=int(key)),
                          ) for key in final_dic]
Rollcall.objects.bulk_create(final_objects)
```

Comment: If in this list exist two item that refer to one user such as: `[['present','2'],['study','2'],...]`, what I must to do ? @benito-h

Comment: does the updated code work for you? Now you are able to set both student and present true

Comment: Yes it did. Is is possible to update your answer with `bulk_create` method to hits database one time ? @benito-h

Comment: try `Rollcall.objects.bulk_create([Rollcall(present=True if 'present' in dic[s_id] else False, study=True if 'study' in dic[s_id], student=User.objects.get(id=int(s_id)) for s_id in dic)])`

Comment: Thanks a a lot. I will edit your question with correct variables and accept it. Please rep me @benito-h

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `list`, create `Rollcall` instances and use `bulk_create()` `Manager`/`QuerySet` method (This avoids a lot of database hits (Only one `INSERT` query will be enough) and gives you guarantee of `atomicity`).

```
data_list = [['present', '2'], ['present', '3'], ['present', '4'], ['study', '1']]

Rollcall.objects.bulk_create([
    Rollcall(present=True if present == 'present' else False, student_id=int(student_id)) for present, student_id in data_list)
])
```

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: I couldn't understand your answer. Explain that. And also pay attention two this notice: each user can have two item in this list (user can be `persent` or not, or can be `study` or not (4 state)). If user have both of them, we must change both field to`True`. Is it your answer consider this notic? And how ? @gachdavit

Comment: You provided us list. `[['present', '2'], ['present', '3'], ['present', '4'], ['study', '1']][['present', '2'], ['present', '3'], ['present', '4'], ['study', '1']]`. `[[present, user_id], [present, user_id]]`. What you mean in 4 state ?

Comment: This is state 1 : `[['present', '1'], ['study', '1'],...]`. This is state 2 : `[ ['study', '1'],...]`. This is state 3 : `[['present', '1'],...]` , and state four occur when user didn't have any of `present` and `study`.@gachdavit

Comment: What is your problem i do not understand ? iterate over your list and make conditional branching and insert data in database. what is blocking factor ?

Comment: Is it possible to edit and explain more in my question? I think that I must write my `forms.py` file and tell you more about problem. @gachdavit