# Update list of records and fields into django model with bulk_update

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

**I want to update the list of records in the my model.** I want to use `bulk_update` more preferably.
These are my data that I have taken from users and want to update them in my model:

```
{'2': ['present', 'study'], '3': ['study'], '4': ['present'], '6': ['no-present', 'no-study']}
```

The numbers represent the user's ID, and the values of each key are also fields that need to be updated.
Also my model is:

```
#models.py
class Rollcall(models.Model):
        student = models.ForeignKey(User)
        curriculum_session = models.ForeignKey(CurriculumSession)
        is_present = models.BooleanField(default=False, )
        is_study = models.BooleanField(default=False,)
```

> This question in the persuit of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56310072/save-list-of-records-and-fields-into-django-model) question In that question, I
>   was able to store my record using `create_bulk` in the database and
>   this question is about updating those data.

**So, how can I do this?** Also I see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_update) link and saw that bulk_update have to argument: 'obj' and 'fields'. **What are these arguments?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `bulk_update(objs, fields, batch_size=None)`

`objs` is a list of the objects you want to update, and `fields` is a list of the fields that you want to update in those objects (meaning the ones you modified).

For example, if your `clean_objects` contains a bunch of `Rollcall` objects, and you want to upadate the `is_present` field from `True` to `False`, you would do

```
roll_call1 = RollCall(...) # assume is_present is True
roll_call2 = RollCall(...) # assume is_present is True

# Update the objects
roll_call1.is_present = False
roll_call2.is_present = False

# Create the list
clean_object = [rollcall_1, rollcall_2,]

# Update in db
Rollcall.objects.bulk_update(clean_objects, ["is_present"])
```

---

Ok, updating with your example. If you have this data

```
data = {'2': ['present', 'study'], '3': ['study'], '4': ['present'], '6': ['no-present', 'no-study']}
```

then you would first retrieve all the `Rollcall` objects referenced in this data (with one query ideally, in the spirit of being efficient and using bulk later). Then you'd update the relevant fields for each object based on the data above. Once all done, call the bulk update method.

```
# Assuming the number in the `data` is the student id and not the rollcall id
rollcalls = Rollcall.objects.filter(student__id__in=data.keys())

for rollcall in rollcalls:
    # Parse the data
    values = data[str(rollcall.student.id)]
    if "present" in values:
        rollcall.is_present = True
    if "no-present" in values:
        rollcall.is_present = False
    if "study" in values:
        rollcall.is_study = True
    if "no-study" in values:
        rollcall.is_study = False

Rollcall.objects.bulk_update(rollcalls, ["is_present", "is_study"])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that my problem is a little different from your answer. So I update my question. @ns0

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot- @ns0